# Managing caching callbacks in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I'm on .NET 4.6.2, MVC 5. Caching is using [`MemoryCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=netframework-4.6.2). I have caching completely written in a controller, complete with item removed callbacks, but then I remembered that controllers are created in request scope. I assume this means that my callbacks won't fire because the controller has been disposed of by that point.

What is the best way to handle this? I know I can query the cache from the controller, that's not an issue, but my question is how I should handle that caching with callbacks.

The only thing I can think of would be a singleton service that runs in the background to manage the cache. That means I would be able to inject it into `Application_Start` and handle initialization, but I'm always wary of using singletons.

How should I handle caching callbacks in MVC 5? It doesn't seem to me that it would work inside a controller because controllers are created per-request.

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to achieve here? Why do you need "callbacks"? FWIW, MemoryCache is process-bound, so it will hang around as long as your App Pool or individual web workers do (each worker is a separate process). So, yes, while controllers are request-scoped, the cache will still likely survive many requests.

Comment: If you're simply trying to add more stability to your cache, you'd do better to look into using Redis. A distributed cache with Redis will be far more robust than anything you'll ever achieve with `MemoryCache`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt We're caching a couple heavy objects from the DB, but they need to refresh every 24 hours. I have the objects set to expire, and before they do I call the relevant callback to update them.

Comment: For any sort of scheduled callback, you should be using something like Hangfire or Revalee. It should be totally independent of your application (though it may utilize your application to do the work). Any attempt to try to schedule some sort of callback in process is doomed to failure as IIS processes are intentionally disposable and are treated as such.

Comment: @ChrisPratt The information I've read seems to indicate that MemoryCache would work just fine for this; this is its intended purpose. It would be overkill for us to use a library just to store a couple objects. The cache items specify that they should never be disposed--.NET will not kill them for memory purposes. The MemoryCache itself is scoped to the app and wouldn't be killed either.

Comment: That's quite incorrect actually. MemoryCache lives and dies with the process and there's any number of reasons the process might be killed. At the very least, by default the app pool recycles after a period of time, and your cache will go with it. You can disable that, but there's many other reasons it might go away. You should never count on anything in MemoryCache persisting for a determined amount of time. It's one of those great if it works, otherwise no biggie situations. If you need true reliability you need to look elsewhere.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Then I'm pretty confused. Why would this even exist if it's pointless to use? The site that I'm updating currently uses application variables, which obviously isn't ideal.

Comment: Well, for one, it's not exclusive to Web apps. Desktop apps in particular would have pretty much a permanent process as long as they are running. Web apps are a different beast. Second, it's still not pointless, as having some cache is better than no cache, and in most cases it would probably work fine. You just can't stick something in it once a day and assume it's always going to be there.

Comment: @ChrisPratt If my only viable option is something like Redis then I won't be able to cache at all. It's not worth figuring that out at this stage for only a couple of variables.

Comment: I recommended Redis because Microsoft has done a lot of work with Redis to integrate it into their platform. It's what Azure uses. I deployed it and was up and running in like 5 minutes. Also, it doesn't have to be *just* for this. There's session and output cache providers provided by Microsoft. So you can use it for pretty much everything. Handling sessions with it is particularly slick, and has greatly improved the performance and stability of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a slightly different method. Caching is still handled in the controller, but I eliminated the callbacks. The controller attempts to access the cached data, and if it doesn't exist it is repopulated. This solves the problem I presented while still being able to utilize the caching.